# rewriting match-lambda

Tags: scheme, racket, match

As an exercise I am trying to define a rule `match-rewriter` that behaves the same as `match-lambda` but returns its argument if no match is found.  So far I have this:

```
(define-syntax match-rewriter
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (patt body) ...)
      (λ (x) (match x (patt body) ...)))))
```

which seems to work perfectly if a match is found.

But, I can't figure out how to return the argument `x` if no match is found.

I know that match will throw an exception if no match is found. But I can't figure out how to catch it and I would like a simpler solution if one exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this question is about the [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/)'s `match`, then just add a clause that matches anything:

```
(match x [patt body] ... [_ x])
```